# Insufficient funds for intrinsic transaction cost on goerli network

Tags: ethereum, solidity, hardhat

I am working on dapp using hardhat and goerli testnet and when I run it using `npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network goerli`, I receive this error, I do have goerli faucet eth on my wallet but still it will display that my account balance is 0:

```
Error: insufficient funds for intrinsic transaction cost [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS ] (error={"name":"ProviderError","_stack":"ProviderError: HttpProviderError\n    at HttpProvider.request (C:\\Users\\SAIFUL\\RTW3-Week7-NFT-Marketplace\\node_modules\\hardhat\\src\\internal\\core\\providers\\http.ts:78:19)\n    at LocalAccountsProvider.request (C:\\Users\\SAIFUL\\RTW3-Week7-NFT-Marketplace\\node_modules\\hardhat\\src\\internal\\core\\providers\\accounts.ts:181:36)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)\n    at EthersProviderWrapper.send (C:\\Users\\SAIFUL\\RTW3-Week7-NFT-Marketplace\\node_modules\\@nomiclabs\\hardhat-ethers\\src\\internal\\ethers-provider-wrapper.ts:13:20)","code":-32000,"_isProviderError":true}, method="sendTransaction", transaction=undefined, code=INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS, version=providers/5.7.2)
    at Logger.makeError (C:\Users\SAIFUL\RTW3-Week7-NFT-Marketplace\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:269:28)
    at Logger.throwError (C:\Users\SAIFUL\RTW3-Week7-NFT-Marketplace\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:281:20)
    at checkError (C:\Users\SAIFUL\RTW3-Week7-NFT-Marketplace\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\src.ts\json-rpc-provider.ts:98:16)
    at C:\Users\SAIFUL\RTW3-Week7-NFT-Marketplace\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\src.ts\json-rpc-provider.ts:265:24
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5) {
  reason: 'insufficient funds for intrinsic transaction cost',
  code: 'INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS',
  error: ProviderError: HttpProviderError
      at HttpProvider.request (C:\Users\SAIFUL\RTW3-Week7-NFT-Marketplace\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\providers\http.ts:78:19)
      at LocalAccountsProvider.request (C:\Users\SAIFUL\RTW3-Week7-NFT-Marketplace\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\providers\accounts.ts:181:36)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
      at EthersProviderWrapper.send (C:\Users\SAIFUL\RTW3-Week7-NFT-Marketplace\node_modules\@nomiclabs\hardhat-ethers\src\internal\ethers-provider-wrapper.ts:13:20),
  method: 'sendTransaction',
  transaction: undefined
}
```

here is my deploy.js file everything is supposed to fine and working but error won't disappear

```
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");
const fs = require('fs');
// const infuraId = fs.readFileSync(".infuraid").toString().trim() || "";

task("accounts", "Prints the list of accounts", async(taskArgs, hre) => {
    const accounts = await hre.ethers.getSigners();

    for (const account of accounts) {
        console.log(account.address);
    }
});

module.exports = {
    defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
    networks: {
        hardhat: {
            chainId: 1337
        },
        goerli: {
            url: "https://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/2Hmp7mz6XEpw6Z47cCZx2vEIAYXFGYOL",
            accounts: ["private key here"]
        }
    },
    solidity: {
        version: "0.8.4",
        settings: {
            optimizer: {
                enabled: true,
                runs: 200
            }
        }
    }
};
```

here is my solidity contract:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "hardhat/console.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

contract NFTMarketplace is ERC721URIStorage {
    address payable owner;

    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;
    Counters.Counter private _itemsSold;

    uint256 listPrice = 0.01 ether;

    constructor() ERC721("NFTMarketplace", "NFTM") {
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
    }

    struct ListedToken {
        uint256 tokenId;
        address payable owner;
        address payable seller;
        uint256 price;
        bool currentlyListed;
    }

    mapping(uint256 => ListedToken) private idToListedToken;

    function updateListPrice(uint256 _listprice) public payable {
        require(owner == msg.sender, "only owner can update listing price ");
        listPrice = _listprice;
    }

    function getListPrice() public view returns (uint256) {
        return listPrice;
    }

    function getLatestIdToListedtoken()
        public
        view
        returns (ListedToken memory)
    {
        uint256 currentTokenId = _tokenIds.current();
        return idToListedToken[currentTokenId];
    }

    function getListedForToken(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (ListedToken memory) {
        return idToListedToken[tokenId];
    }

    function getCurrentToken() public view returns (uint256) {
        return _tokenIds.current();
    }

    function createToken(string memory tokenURI, uint256 price) public payable returns (uint) {
        require(msg.value == listPrice, "Send enough ether to list");
        require(price > 0, "Make sure the price isn't negative");

        _tokenIds.increment();
        uint256 currentTokenId = _tokenIds.current();
        _safeMint(msg.sender, currentTokenId);

        _setTokenURI(currentTokenId, tokenURI);

        createListedToken(currentTokenId, price);

        return currentTokenId;
    }

    function createListedToken(uint256 tokenId, uint256 price) private {
        idToListedToken[tokenId] = ListedToken(
            tokenId, 
            payable(address(this)),
            payable(msg.sender),
            price,
            true
        );

        _transfer(msg.sender, address(this), tokenId);
    }

    function getAllNFTs() public view returns(ListedToken[] memory) {
        uint nftCount = _tokenIds.current();
        ListedToken[] memory tokens = new ListedToken[](nftCount);

        uint currentIndex = 0;

        for(uint i=0; i<nftCount; i++) {
            uint currentId = i+1;
            ListedToken storage currentItem = idToListedToken[currentId];
            tokens[currentIndex] = currentItem;
            currentIndex += 1;
        }

        return tokens;
    }

    function getMyNFTs() public view returns (ListedToken[] memory) {
        uint totalItemCount = _tokenIds.current();
        uint itemCount = 0;
        uint currentIndex = 0;
        uint currentId;
        for(uint i=0; i < totalItemCount; i++)
        {
            if(idToListedToken[i+1].owner == msg.sender || idToListedToken[i+1].seller == msg.sender){
                itemCount += 1;
            }
        }

        ListedToken[] memory items = new ListedToken[](itemCount);
        for(uint i=0; i < totalItemCount; i++) {
            if(idToListedToken[i+1].owner == msg.sender || idToListedToken[i+1].seller == msg.sender) {
                currentId = i+1;
                ListedToken storage currentItem = idToListedToken[currentId];
                items[currentIndex] = currentItem;
                currentIndex += 1;
            }
        }
        return items;
    }

    function executeSale(uint256 tokenId) public payable {
        uint price = idToListedToken[tokenId].price;
        require(msg.value == price, "please submit the relevant NFT price in order to purchase");

        address seller = idToListedToken[tokenId].seller;

        idToListedToken[tokenId].currentlyListed = true;
        idToListedToken[tokenId].seller = payable(msg.sender);
        _itemsSold.increment();

        _transfer(address(this), msg.sender, tokenId);

        approve(address(this), tokenId);

        payable(owner).transfer(listPrice);
        payable(seller).transfer(msg.value);

    }
}
```

I tried different networks, but I have no choice except goerli because I will use alchemy Api.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? Currently facing the same issue with similar config.

Comment: I guess is a network issue...cause this is happening to me right now, and yesterday in stead was working normally.

Answer (score 0):

You still need to get more Goerli ETH from faucets or from your other peers.
Try that and see if it will work

Answer (score 0):

Finally I switched from INFURA to ALCHEMY and following the instructions here:

https://hardhat.org/tutorial/deploying-to-a-live-network

it worked!